# How to add multiple effects to a picture such as contrast and brightness at the same time

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I created a simple program using python to change picture Contrast,Brightness color and etc. First I just added one effect, and it worked well, I managed to link it with a Scaler. Then I tried to add multiple effect at once which I've also linked with scalers, but when I try to add multiple effects on the picture (e.g Contrast and brightness at the same time) I got a grey Screen, or just nothing happened to the picture.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance


def main():
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("400x290")
    window.configure(background="#EBEBEB")
    OpenB = ttk.Button(window, text="Import Photo")
    OpenB.pack()

    def onClickImport():
        askimage = askopenfilename()
        global img
        img=Image.open(askimage)

    OpenB.config(command=onClickImport)
    window.mainloop()
    window2 = Tk()
    window2.geometry("400x290")
    window2.configure(background="#EBEBEB")

    DisplayButton=ttk.Button(window2,text="Show")
    DisplayButton.pack()
    ScalerContrast= ttk.Scale(window2, from_=1.0, to_=5.0)
    ScalerContrast.pack()
    ScalerBrightness = ttk.Scale(window2, from_=1.0, to_=5.0)
    ScalerBrightness.pack()
    ScalerColor = ttk.Scale(window2, from_=1, to_=100)
    ScalerColor.pack()
    ScalerSharpness = ttk.Scale(window2, from_=1, to_=100)
    ScalerSharpness.pack()

    textCon=Text(window2,width=8,height=1)
    textCon.insert(END,"Contrast")
    textCon.config(state=DISABLED)
    textCon.configure(background="#EBEBEB")
    textCon.configure(font="Roboto")
    textCon.pack()

    textBr=Text(window2,width=8,height=1)
    textBr.insert(END,"Brightness")
    textBr.config(state=DISABLED)
    textBr.configure(background="#EBEBEB")
    textBr.configure(font="Roboto")
    textBr.pack()

    textCor=Text(window2,width=8,height=1)
    textCor.insert(END,"Color")
    textCor.config(state=DISABLED)
    textCor.configure(background="#EBEBEB")
    textCor.configure(font="Roboto")
    textCor.pack()

    textSh=Text(window2,width=8,height=1)
    textSh.insert(END,"Sharpness")
    textSh.config(state=DISABLED)
    textSh.configure(background="#EBEBEB")
    textSh.configure(font="Roboto")
    textSh.pack()

    converter = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img)
    converter1= ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)
    converter2= ImageEnhance.Color(img)
    converter3= ImageEnhance.Sharpness(img)

    def onClickDisplay():
        img2=converter.enhance(ScalerContrast.get()) and converter1.enhance(ScalerBrightness.get()) and\
        converter2.enhance(ScalerColor.get())   and converter3.enhance(ScalerColor.get())
        img2.show()

    DisplayButton.config(command=onClickDisplay)

    window2.mainloop()


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!
First of all, you don't have to use `config` for all your Buttons, Text widgets and so on - you can simply give all those options as arguments when you're creating a widget, e.g.

```
textCon = Text(window2, width=8, height=1, state=DISABLED, background="#EBEBEB", font="Roboto")
```

This makes your code shorter, simpler and faster.
What you're doing in `onClickDisplay` does not work for a simple reason. You are using `and`, which is a boolean operator, to try to make multiple things happen at once - which is not what `and` is about. This is how i would rewrite your code:

```
class CustomImageEnhancer()
    def __init__(self):

        def onClickImport():
            askimg = fd.askopenfilename()
            self.img = Image.open(askimage)
            return self.img

        def converted_image(img_a, contrast, brightness, color, sharpness):
            contrast_converter = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img_a)
            img_b = contrast_converter.enhance(contrast)
            brightness_converter = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img_b)
            img_c = brightness_converter.enhance(brightness)
            color_converter = ImageEnhance.Color(img_c)
            img_d = color_converter.enhance(color)
            sharpness_converter = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(img_d)
            img_final = sharpness_converter.enhance(sharpness)
            return img_final

        def onClickDisplay():
            cont = ScalerContrast.get()
            bright = ScalerBrightness.get()
            col = ScalerColor.get()
            sharp = ScalerSharpness.get()
            img = self.img
            new_img = converted_image(img, cont, bright, col, sharp)
            new_img.show()

        root = Tk()
        OpenB = ttk.Button(root, text="Import Photo", command=onClickImport)
        OpenB.pack()

        DisplayButton=ttk.Button(root, text="Show", command=onClickDisplay)
        ScalerContrast= ttk.Scale(root, from_=1.0, to_=5.0)
        ScalerBrightness = ttk.Scale(root, from_=1.0, to_=5.0)
        ScalerColor = ttk.Scale(root, from_=1, to_=100)
        ScalerSharpness = ttk.Scale(root, from_=1, to_=100)

        DisplayButton.pack()
        ScalerContrast.pack()
        ScalerBrightness.pack()
        ScalerColor.pack()
        ScalerSharpness.pack()

        textCon=Text(root, width=8, height=1, state=DISABLED, background="#EBEBEB", font='Roboto')
        textCon.insert(END, 'Contrast')
        textCon.pack()

        textBr=Text(root, width=8, height=1, state=DISABLED, background='#EBEBEB', font='Roboto')
        textBr.insert(END, 'Brightness')
        textBr.pack()

        textCor=Text(root, width=8, height=1, state=DISABLED, background='#EBEBEB', font='Roboto')
        textCor.insert(END, 'Color')
        textCor.pack()

        textSh=Text(root, width=8, height=1, state=DISABLED, background='#EBEBEB', font='Roboto')
        textSh.insert(END, 'Color')
        textSh.pack()

        root.mainloop()


window=CustomImageEnhancer()
```

By defining a class, you can work around having to use global variables. Opening two windows is not necessary in your case, as you can just add the button for choosing the image file to your other window. I would recommend using `place()` instead of `pack()`, as it will allow you to define exact x and y coordinates for your different widgets inside the window, which will make it look more structured - `pack` simply places widgets one after another.

Comment: It works !! thank you very much, I used your idea in my code without using classes, because I really hate them.

Comment: Very glad i could help! Alright, that's your choice :) Have a nice day!